# How can I include something with each switch statement in JS?

Tags: javascript

**UPDATE:** On second thought, I could reset the values immediately outside of the switch statement. To do so, I'd need to check whether or not the case has changed to the NEXT case value. For example, if I my values are  currently on Case 1 (1 sec into the game), how can I check when the timer has gone to the NEXT value (in this case, 30).  What do you believe is a simple way of doing that?

---

I'm creating a game which has a running timer, **current.getTime()**. Events are triggered at different timestamps within the game. I set all of the variables for these events within a switch statement.

Most of the variables change with each case, but there are two which get reset to their default value in each statement:

1) current.GetTime()
2) setTrapSprung(false);

**How can I reset these values without having to place it inside of EACH case?** In the end, I will have 100+ cases, so it's 200+ lines of code to repeat.

**NOTE:** I cannot set these values outside of the switch statement (for example, right after the case has been set), because during that period between events, a user may actually spring a trap, thereby setting the value to true.

```
  var eventsHallOne         = function () {
      switch (current.getTime()) {
        // 1st second in the game
        case 1:
            room.hallOne.setCurUrl(camHallOne.c21);
            room.hallOne.setNextUrl(null);
            room.hallOne.setTrapUrl(camHallOne.c130422);
            room.hallOne.setCatchTime(3);

            /* How do I reset these two variables for EACH statement, without having to set them within
             * each statement? Each time an event occurs, they will have their value reset to what you see below. */
            room.hallOne.setTime(current.getTime());
            room.hallOne.setTrapSprung(false);
            break;
        // 30 seconds into the game 
        case 30:
            room.hallOne.setCurUrl(camHallOne.c6543);
            room.hallOne.setNextUrl(null);
            room.hallOne.setTrapUrl(camHallOne.c123522);
            room.hallOne.setCatchTime(6);
            room.hallOne.setTime(current.getTime());
            room.hallOne.setTrapSprung(false);
          break;
        // 45 seconds into the game
        case 45:
            room.hallOne.setCurUrl(camHallOne.c53);
            room.hallOne.setNextUrl(null);
            room.hallOne.setTrapUrl(camHallOne.c130);
            room.hallOne.setCatchTime(15);
            room.hallOne.setTime(current.getTime());
            room.hallOne.setTrapSprung(false);
            break;
        }
  /* Could reset the values here if I could detect that the case has   changed. Unsure of how to do so, however. */
};
```

Comment: This approach of using hundreds or even dozens of switch statements is going to be a nightmare to maintain, read, or update. You should really consider changing your design before you get too far along. It will scale much better if you incorporate some design patterns to manage these states and data.

Comment: Believe me, I agree! 

I'm trying to take gameplay from a Sega CD game written in 68k assembly and repurpose it for the browser.  

http://www.davevoyles.com/deconstructing-night-trap/

Comment: Have you ever looked at writing a boggle solver? It is a really simple thing to do, and I am sure you will be able to write one very quickly with your skill set. What I would like to highlight from that process is something known as a trie. I would suggest organizing your conditional statements into results of parsing the relevant numbers. This way, parsing a number will follow the path of the trie and lead you to your end result. It will allow for overlapping functionality and such as well.

Comment: @TravisJ No, I haven't considered that before. I'm going to look into that, as well as a trie right now. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kinda hack, but it might help you:

How about inverting the logic of switch by adding `default` branch that gets triggered if none of the cases is entered, set some temporaty variable there and after switch, reset those varaibles if the default case was NOT entered?

```
  var eventsHallOne         = function () {

      var importantTimeAchieved = true;

      switch (current.getTime()) {
        // 1st second in the game
        case 1:
            room.hallOne.setCurUrl(camHallOne.c21);
            room.hallOne.setNextUrl(null);
            room.hallOne.setTrapUrl(camHallOne.c130422);
            room.hallOne.setCatchTime(3);
        break;

        // 30 seconds into the game 
        case 30:
            room.hallOne.setCurUrl(camHallOne.c6543);
            room.hallOne.setNextUrl(null);
            room.hallOne.setTrapUrl(camHallOne.c123522);
            room.hallOne.setCatchTime(6);
          break;

        // 45 seconds into the game
        case 45:
            room.hallOne.setCurUrl(camHallOne.c53);
            room.hallOne.setNextUrl(null);
            room.hallOne.setTrapUrl(camHallOne.c130);
            room.hallOne.setCatchTime(15);
            break;

        // none of important times
        default:
            importantTimeAchieved = false;
        }

    if (importantTimeAchieved) {
        room.hallOne.setTime(current.getTime());
        room.hallOne.setTrapSprung(false);        
    }

};
```

Comment: Wow, this is it! Incredibly simple, but exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you. That's what I get for staring at code all day and not taking a break.

Answer (score 3):

> I cannot set these values outside of the switch statement (for example, right after the case has been set), because during that period between events, a user may actually spring a trap, thereby setting the value to true.

Wrong. Your `eventsHallOne` function will run to completion before any other events will be processed - javascript is singlethreaded. Notice that even if it wasn't, there is absolutely no difference between doing it after the previous statement in the `case` block or after the previous statement after the `switch` block.

You can, and should, move it simply at the end of your function.

If you want the `default` case to do nothing, just put a `return;` in there so that the statements after the `switch` block are no more executed.

Comment: I understand that it is single threaded, but the issue is difficult to explain without going into paragraphs about the exact issue with the game. I'll post be here when it is complete though, as it will help visualize the issue!  

This eventsHallOne() function gets called each frame (60x sec), so that value would constantly be reset. The problem w/ moving it to the end of the function though, is that it resets the value every frame, thereby negating any input the user may have selected.

Comment: @DaveVoyles-MSFT: I understood your question so that you need to execute those two statements in *every* case?

Comment: Yes, within every case. 

So the values would be set at the 1 second mark, then whatever happens between 1 sec and 30 sec (the next case), the user can change the value of. For example, springing a trap.

So, if the trap has been sprung, and the next case appears (30 secs), the values will all be reset

Comment: @DaveVoyles-MSFT: Do you mean that your cases are not total, and the statements should not be executed when the current time is between 1s and 30s?

Comment: Are not total?

The values are set at each time stamp (1, 30, 45, etc.,), and the user can make changes between each of those stamps.

For example, if the user does trigger a trap, the value of hallone.GetTrapSprung() would equal 'True'. 

At the 30 second mark, I'd like it reset, so that the user has an opportunity to catch something again.

Comment: @DaveVoyles-MSFT I'm still having a hard time understanding what you mean by "between those stamps" if we only take this function as context. So you expect to sometimes call this function when none of the cases is matched and no statements should be executed? (which make the switch [partial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function))

Answer (score 1):

Its not just the last two lines that are repeating.  You are repeating six lines with only the values you are passing changing.

Put all six lines in a function and call the function in your switch statement.

```
function buildState(curUrl, nextUrl, trapUrl, catchTime) {
    room.hallOne.setCurUrl(curUrl);
    room.hallOne.setNextUrl(nextUrl);
    room.hallOne.setTrapUrl(trapUrl);
    room.hallOne.setCatchTime(catchTime);
    room.hallOne.setTime(current.getTime());
    room.hallOne.setTrapSprung(false);
}

....

case 1:
     buildState(camHallOne.c21, null, camHallOne.c130422, 3);
     break;

....
```

Better yet, create a lookup array and use that instead.

```
var timeStates = [
    {"id": 1, state: {curUrl: camHallOne.c21, 
                      nextUrl: null, 
                      trapUrl:  camHallOne.c130422,
                      catchTime: 15  }
]);
```

Then you could add new states to the array and your case statement (which would probably change to a loop) would never need to change.

By they way, this question is perfect for StackExchange Code Review.

Comment: StackExchange Code Review?

Oh yeah, I'm all for people criticizing the code. I'm quickly throwing it together, so I'm wide open to suggestions and ways to improve it. I know it's gross.

Comment: I like this answer. It's much cleaner, and more concise from what I doing previously.

Answer (score 1):

Bit twisted, but change the switch to a closure object with functions:

```
var eventsHallOne = (function(){
    var events = {
        "1": function hallOne1Sec() {
            room.hallOne.setCurUrl( camHallOne.c21 );
            room.hallOne.setNextUrl( null );
            room.hallOne.setTrapUrl( camHallOne.c130422 );
            room.hallOne.setCatchTime( 3 );
        },
        "30": function hallOne30Sec() {
            room.hallOne.setCurUrl( camHallOne.c6543 );
            room.hallOne.setNextUrl( null );
            room.hallOne.setTrapUrl( camHallOne.c123522 );
            room.hallOne.setCatchTime( 6 );
        },
        "45": function hallOne45Sec() {
            room.hallOne.setCurUrl( camHallOne.c53 );
            room.hallOne.setNextUrl( null );
            room.hallOne.setTrapUrl( camHallOne.c130 );
            room.hallOne.setCatchTime( 15 );
        }
    }

    return function eventsHallOne() {
        var time = current.getTime().toString();
        var foundEvent = events[time];
        if ( foundEvent !== undefined ) {
            foundEvent();
            room.hallOne.setTime( current.getTime() );
            room.hallOne.setTrapSprung( false );
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: That's a really clever way of doing it, which I hadn't considered before.  I'm going to look into re-arranging it this way.  

It's only going to grow larger and larger, so I need to figure out how to slim it down with the fewest mistakes.

Comment: also name anon functions (like returned one) else debugging stack traces say: (anonymous function) which makes things harder.

Comment: Even better than making all those functions would be to have objects like `{curUrl: amHallOne.c2, nextUrl: null, trapUrl: camHallOne.c130422, catchTime: 3}`.